# Validated-method fires and returns undefined error

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to implement `mdg:validated-method` to `insert` a new collection, however, my code returns an `undefined` error message. The `console.log(profileCandidate)` after `run` returns the object. It appears to stop working at `insert`.

Path: `imports/api/profileCandidate/methods.js`

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
import { ValidatedMethod } from 'meteor/mdg:validated-method';

import ProfileCandidate from './profileCandidate.js';

export const insertProfileCandidate = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'profileCandidate.insert',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    'firstName': { type: String },
  }).validator(),
  run(profileCandidate) {
    console.log("profileCandidate", profileCandidate);

    ProfileCandidate.insert({
      userId: Meteor.userId(),
      createdAt: new Date(),
      name: {
        first: profileCandidate.firstName,
      },
    });
  },
});
```

Path: `imports/api/profileCandidate/profileCandidate.js`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';

export const ProfileCandidate = new Mongo.Collection('profileCandidate');

ProfileCandidate.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  userId: {
    type: String,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
  },
  name: Object,
    'name.first': String,
});

ProfileCandidate.attachSchema(ProfileCandidate.schema);
```

Comment: Enable debug mode for the simple schema package `SimpleSchema.debug = true`, anything helpful?

Comment: No error appears. It's almost as if the `ProfileCandidate.insert` doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there wasn't an error in the method. The error was in how I was importing the schema. I needed to change `import ProfileCandidate from './profileCandidate.js';` to `import { ProfileCandidate } from './profileCandidate.js';`. If anyone can shed some light on why you need curly braces, in this case, I would appreciate it.

Comment: If you had done `export default const insertProfileCandidate` from your schema file then you could have used the import without the `{}`